# How to read slicing with negative step

Tags: python, list, slice

I have already seen some questions about slicing, but haven't seen a helpful answer concerning some of them, which I can't manage to understand very well.
Let's say we have this list `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
And I slice it in the following way:

```
a[:8:-1] #Ouput: [9]
```

Why? We give it an end of 8, and a step of -1. How come it behaves in this way?

Comment: Out of curiosity - did you have something else in mind that the output should be?

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be an empty list (I didn't know that [:2] == [None:2])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you omit the first part of the slice expression, it defaults to `None`. When it comes time for `list.__getitem__` to interpret what `slice(None, 8, -1)` means, it uses the sign of the step size to determine if you are counting up from 0 or down from the end of the list. In this case, you are counting down, so `:8:-1` is equivalent to `slice(-1, 8, -1)`.