# What's the default start and stop for python slicing index?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
a = np.ramdon.rand(10)

# We can index a numpy array by [start:stop(:step)]

a[::1]  # returns [a[0], a[1], ..., a[9]]
a[::-1]  # returns [a[9], a[8], ..., a[0]]
```

As shown in the above example, `start` and `stop` for both `a[::1]` and `a[::-1]` should be by default, since only the `step` arguments are given. For `a[::1]`, I suppose the default `start` should be 0 and the default `stop` should be -1 (i.e., `a[::1]` is the same as `a[0:-1:1]`), but apparently this is not true for `a[::-1]`, since `a[0:-1:-1]` returns an empty array. So what are the exact default setting for `stop` and `start`? I am so confused because all the documentations I ran into only mentioned that to reverse an array you can use `::-1` with no further explanation.

Comment: All the defaults are `None`... you can just do `something[:]` or `something[::]` for instance... basically if start is `None` then it's 0 and if end is `None` it's considered `len(obj)` and step if not given defaults to 1...

Comment: However, if step is negative, then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920270/how-to-read-slicing-with-negative-step/59920309#59920309

Comment: eg: if you had a list `r = list(range(20))` - then you can take every third element just using `r[::3]`... (which'll give you `[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]`) and then you could use `[::-1]` on that to reverse it, but if you wanted to do stepping backwards to begin with you'd need to do `r[-2::-3]`

Comment: @JonClements So when the step is negative, it counts down from the last element by default when `start` is not given, while when the step is positive, it counts up from the first element by default, right?

Comment: Depends what `end` is set as :) Looks like you've got some good links to read though... most of it is quite intuitive - the bits that aren't immediately you'll never really have to worry about anyway.

Comment: @JonClements I just read those links. Based on my current understanding, I think it actually has nothing to do with the `end`. If the `start` is not given, for a positive `step`, the `start` is by default 0, and for a negative `step`, it's by default -1.

Comment: Put simply, the default is the value that gives the maximum range - the `whole` thing if the user doesn't limit it.

Comment: @hpaulj This interpretation is pretty clear.